# Dynamic COUNT in JPA throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, jpa, nullpointerexception, criteria

My goal is to make a method with which I can retrieve the total number of rows from any table in my database.

**This is what I have done:**

```
ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
EM = ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.createEntityManager();

public static long getRowCount(Root<?> root) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = EM.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

    root = query.from(root.getClass());
    query.select(cb.count(root));

    return EM.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}
```

**This is how I call the method:**

```
Root<PlacesEntity> placesRoot = null;
DbTools.getRowCount(placesRoot)
```

It is not working though, the method throws a `NullPointerException` at the line `root = query.from(root.getClass());`.

Comment: I'm not sure how a java method can crash without any exception.  Is the JVM terminated, or is the calling method just catching and ignoring Exceptions?  Also note that an EntityManager is not thread safe, so probably shouldn't be initialized and used statically.  Try turning on logging and see if you are missing something.

Comment: @Chris I set a generic try catch and looks like it throws a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (*warning not tested*):

```
public static long getRowCount(Class<?> rootClass) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = EM.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

    Expression<?> root = query.from(rootClass);
    query.select(cb.count(root));

    return EM.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}

/*****/
DbTools.getRowCount(PlacesEntity.class);
```

Good luck!

Comment: This worked! So what happens is that I basically pass the class as a parameter?

Comment: For `query.from` you need just the entity class. In your code, you were using `Root` class instead `PlacesEntity` class.